# How to automatically deploy code to newly created EC2 instances under ASG with codedeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, aws-code-deploy

I have 2 EC2 instances under ASG. I created Application1 in codeDeploy with DeploymentGroup1 that is set to use Autoscaling.

The issue I'm facing is that when new EC2 instance is provisioned, codedeploy doesn't create new deployment and code is not pushed to instances. It doesn't look like there's a log to even see what's going on.

When I list hooks for my Autoscaling Group I do see them:

```
$ aws autoscaling describe-lifecycle-hooks --auto-scaling-group-name SAND-web-ASG 
{
    "LifecycleHooks": [
        {
            "GlobalTimeout": 60000,
            "HeartbeatTimeout": 600,
            "AutoScalingGroupName": "SAND-web-ASG",
            "LifecycleHookName": "CodeDeploy-managed-automatic-launch-deployment-hook-DeployToNewEC2underASG-...",
            "NotificationMetadata": "....",
            "DefaultResult": "ABANDON",
            "NotificationTargetARN": "arn:aws:sqs:us-west-1:blabla:blahh-us-west-1-prod-default-autoscaling-lifecycle-hook",
            "LifecycleTransition": "autoscaling:EC2_INSTANCE_LAUNCHING"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there something missing or wrong here?? These are not custom, these are created by codedeploy.

I was following the [guide to setup codedeploy with ASG](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/integrations-aws-auto-scaling.html) and everything is created but for some reason when new instances is created codedeploy doesn't create new deployment.. and I'm kind of lost why..

My Service role has 2 IAM policies:

1 - default from amazon AWSCodedeployRole

2 - codePipelinePolicy (custom) with the following permissions:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction",
        "autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
        "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat",
        "autoscaling:CreateAutoScalingGroup",
        "autoscaling:UpdateAutoScalingGroup",
        "autoscaling:EnableMetricsCollection",
        "autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups",
        "autoscaling:DescribePolicies",
        "autoscaling:DescribeScheduledActions",
        "autoscaling:DescribeNotificationConfigurations",
        "autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks",
        "autoscaling:SuspendProcesses",
        "autoscaling:ResumeProcesses",
        "autoscaling:AttachLoadBalancers",
        "autoscaling:PutScalingPolicy",
        "autoscaling:PutScheduledUpdateGroupAction",
        "autoscaling:PutNotificationConfiguration",
        "autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook",
        "autoscaling:DescribeScalingActivities",
        "autoscaling:DeleteAutoScalingGroup",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances",
        "tag:GetTags",
        "tag:GetResources",
        "sns:Publish",
        "cloudwatch:DescribeAlarms",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeLoadBalancers",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DescribeInstanceHealth",
        "elasticloadbalancing:RegisterInstancesWithLoadBalancer",
        "elasticloadbalancing:DeregisterInstancesFromLoadBalancer"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Am I missing something here or maybe there's something wrong(stupid mistake) that I'm not seeing?

Any advice really appreciated.
Thank you,
Ernest

Comment: Is the CodeDeploy agent installed and running on these EC2 instances? If not, it needs to be. If it is, check logs from the CodeDeploy agent (in /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/deployment-logs).

Comment: Yes, agent is installed.<br/>
It's Amazon Linux OS, log is under /var/log/aws/codedeploy-agent/codedeploy-agent.log <br/>
and it shows <br/>
`2017-07-19 15:17:13 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3534)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.
2017-07-19 15:18:13 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3534)]: [Aws::CodeDeployCommand::Client 200 60.290274 0 retries] poll_host_command(host_identifier:"arn:aws:ec2:us-west-1:<ACCOUNT-ID>:instance/i-<INSTANCE-ID>")

2017-07-19 15:18:14 INFO  [codedeploy-agent(3534)]: Version file found in /opt/codedeploy-agent/.version.`  <br/>
Thanks

Comment: If you haven't already, review the troubleshooting guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/troubleshooting.html).

Answer (score 0):

From you description, I am not seeing you mention having performed a successful deployment to your application. During a scale up, CodeDeploy will try to deploy the target revision of your application, but if none is found, then it will not issue a deployment at all, which will lead to the issue you are seeing. You should performed a deployment to update the target revision of your application, and then try scaling up and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: The problem was missing permissions. After I correctly setup IAM policies everything started working.

Comment: Has anyone been successful in writing lambda function for creating codedeploy deployments?
I have post on AWS [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=796320#796320) but seems like people here are much faster.
Thanks in advance.